# Can I increase the size of the duck?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, quack-overflow

Can the duck be made bigger? How?

Comment: BTW I also want a purple duck. How to change color?

Comment: Have you tried talking louder?

Comment: @JonEricson Sorry I don't talk to ducks... I just want to change size and color. Can it be done yes or no?

Comment: Oh well I guess no one cares about color, ill delete question tomorrow...

Comment: Having a big purple duck can be a cause for concern...

Comment: Move closer to the screen.

Comment: @Jon can be ultra hilarious if the duck would actually grow the louder we speak.... :D

Comment: This should have been asked on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Zooooom it.. ;)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted so much?

Comment: @Aaron Because it is pretty much off-topic now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can embiggen the duck by adding this CSS rule, for example using Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)/[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)):

```
.quackoverflow{
    transform: scale(4);
    margin-bottom:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
    bottom:-240px;
}
```

To make it purple, you can also add:

```
.quackoverflow svg g path:nth-child(2){fill:#d5aaff!important;}
.quackoverflow svg g path:nth-child(3),.quackoverflow svg g path:nth-child(4){fill:#b94cff!important;}
```

Should look like this:

[image]

Comment: awesome way to go :) all you down voters take that purple big duck !

Comment: Purple duck! Genius!

Comment: Yes, you can can help me!